# Alternative to folder pages

Tags: navigation, folder, publishing

I have a publishing site, for which I've blocked application pages for read-only users, because I don't want them seeing the ribbon with the edit controls etc. - I know that most of the controls are grayed out for read-only users, but I'd rather just block access to the ribbon entirely to save any confusion or experimentation.

However, I want them to be able to access top-level pages for page folders, or at least a page that shows the contents of each folder.

Before I blocked application pages, the default ToC showed the folder structure, which is great for easy navigation, but now that application pages are blocked for those users, the default ToC just shows the pages individually, with no indication of the folder in which they reside.

Which is the best way to present folder structure in a publishing page? I've looked through the web parts but there is nothing AFAIK that replicates the default ToC but avoids the use of application folder pages.

I may decide to use navigation term sets, if that's relevant at all...

edit: I already have a content query on my home page that displays a list of the pages targeted to the user via audience targeting, but it just shows the permission group name and then a flat list of pages under the group name. which has the effect of presenting the relevant pages but doesn't allow navigation between folders.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have a solution - please let me know if there's a better way:

1. Create navigation terms named as per the folders
2. Create a landing publishing page for each term
3. Add a Content Query web part configured to display pages that match the relevant criteria (in my case, a 'platform' property which relates to the content type)
4. Point the navigation terms to the landing pages
5. Add a ToC web part to my home page which shows the managed navigation term sets.

It feels like a bit of a workaround but should be fairly manageable.